# URL for the Facebook "Empty Man" Profile Picture

Tags: facebook-graph-api

What's the graph URL for the "Empty Man" profile picture, i.e:

[image]

I always thought it was [https://graph.facebook.com/**123**/picture](https://graph.facebook.com/123/picture), until recently it was working. But now it seems like this is an actual user and they have uploaded a photo.

I wanted to avoid making a copy of the image, I thought there must be a graph url.

Comment: http://profile.ak.fbcdn.net/static-ak/rsrc.php/v2/yo/r/UlIqmHJn-SK.gif